# Self-referencing from inside an Excel VBA control

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to get a property value of a button control from inside the button's click event without using the button's name (since I want to use the same code for each of many buttons on the Excel sheet).

After much research, I see many references to try the following:

```
Me.ActiveControl.name
```

or

```
Me.Shapes(Application.Caller).Name
```

However, both of those throw an error when executed from within Excel.  Note that I'm using Excel 2010.

Thanks for any help in advance.
Lee

Comment: Where is the code located? In a standard module?

Comment: The code is located inside the _Click event of the button itself

Comment: What is the specific error message you get?  I agree with @CoolBlue.  "Me" would usually refer to the worksheet where the code is running, but I bet your code is not in a worksheet, it's in a regular module. I'd bet your error is "Invalid use of 'Me' keyword."

Answer (score 3):

What you want is possible but for that you need to create a `Class`

Do this.

Insert a Class Module and paste this code there.

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents MyButton As MSForms.CommandButton

Private Sub MyButton_Click()
    MsgBox MyButton.Name
End Sub
```

[image]

Next Insert a module and place this code there

```
Dim shpButtons() As New Class1

Sub StartCode()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim btnCount As Long

    ReDim shpButtons(1 To 1)

    btnCount = 0

    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If shp.OLEFormat.Object.OLEType = xlOLEControl Then
            btnCount = btnCount + 1
            ReDim Preserve shpButtons(1 To btnCount)
            Set shpButtons(btnCount).MyButton = shp.OLEFormat.Object.Object
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Sub StopCode()
    Dim iBtn As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    For iBtn = LBound(shpButtons) To UBound(shpButtons)
        Set shpButtons(iBtn).TheText = Nothing
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Now simply run the `Sub StartCode()`

Next when you click the ActiveX CommandButton then you will get it's name.

[image]

Comment: Good answer for ActiveX controls, but OP doesn't actually _say_ he's using ActiveX.

Comment: @chrisneilsen: Yes, he doesn't :) From what I could make out from the first sentence, OP is trying to run the code from the `inside the button's click event` and 2ndly `Application.Caller` will give you an error for ActiveX controls. But let's see what OP has to say.

Comment: Interested in your comment that _Application.Caller will give you an error for Form controls._ - I tried it, seems to work for me

Comment: @chrisneilsen: Sorry that was a typo... I meant ActiveX Control. I have amended the comment.

Comment: @chrisneilsen: Thank You :) However you may never know ;) OP might actually be talking about Form Controls :D

Comment: @siddharthrout Thank you for the detailed response. Yes, I'm using ActiveX controls. The sample code provided does exactly what I was trying to do.

Comment: Nice post! Perhaps Chip Pearson has to update [his page](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx)? +1

Answer (score 1):

Try `ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Name`

Comment: I get `Run-time error '-2147352571 (80020005)': The item with the specified name wasn't found.` The issue is with `Application.Caller`, since `Debug.Print TypeName(Application.Caller)` returns `Error`.