# Excel VBA 2010 self reference a Active X button from within it's own action

Tags: vba, excel, activex

i am trying to have an active X control in Excel 2010 get it's own alternate text and display it in a Text box when it is moused over.

If i use an absolute reference `.Shapes("CommandButton1").AlternativeText` it gets the text and i can do what i want with it, however i want a more dynamic function so the same code can be used on multiple buttons without edits so that it will always get the initiating button's own alt text.

I found this in my research, [Self-referencing from inside an Excel VBA control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20293850/self-referencing-from-inside-an-excel-vba-control)
It seems like it would do what i need but when i run the module it throws a Runtime error 13, Type mismatch on this line `Set shpButtons(btnCount).MyButton = shp.OLEFormat.Object.Object`

If it matters i am trying to do this on a MouseMove event, however when i tested the code from the previous thread i was using direct clicks to see if it would would in the first place, which it did not, giving the Type mismatch error.

Any help getting this to work would be appreciated.

Thank you all so much in advance, lin.