# Excel VBA Toggle Button reference with 'Me' keyword

Tags: excel, vba, object, this

In order to keep my code universal and short I would like to use the 'Me' keyword (something like 'This' in other languages) on dozens of Toggle Buttons so I don't need to update the code of ALL Toggle Buttons when my function changes.

Is there some way to reference an Excel VBA Form Toggle Button (or any other object) with the keyword 'Me'?

for example from this:

```
Private Sub ToggleButton01_Click()
    MsgBox myFunction(ToggleButton01.Value, ToggleButton01.Name)
End Sub
```

to that:

```
Private Sub ToggleButton01_Click()
    MsgBox myFunction(Me.Value, Me.Name)
End Sub
```

It seems that the 'Me' keyword works only on Parent Objects (like Workbook, Worksheet, UserForm, Module)

Any other way to reference the Toggle Button?
Many thanks in advance
Pete

Comment: I think this is the closest you can get: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20293850/self-referencing-from-inside-an-excel-vba-control

Comment: @MichalPalko: Okay, nice. So I'll have to teach myself working with VBA Classes. That'll take a while...

Comment: Actually I found solution. Check edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can do something like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
     Me.ActiveControl.Caption
End Sub
```